# Wrap command with options in fish function

Tags: fish

Is there a way to wrap a command with options in a function, so that completions for that command with the options are shown?

For example, I want to be able to do this:

```
function remove --wraps='pikaur -R'
    pikaur -R $argv;
end
```

so that using `remove` will complete with the installed packages, but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `--wraps` argument only accepts a bare command. You can use `--wraps='pikaur'` but not `--wraps='pikaur -R'`.

If the completions you want are only triggered when the `-R` flag is given, using `--wraps` may not be enough. You would need to add your own completions file. Fortunately, Fish makes this very simple.

Is there a command that lets you query or list the valid options? I'm not familiar with `pikaur`, but for example, let's say the valid arguments to your function were given given by a command like `pikaur ls` or `pikaur query`, or perhaps they're subdirectories of `/etc/pikaur`. If there is such a command, you can create a completions file for your function (i.e. if your function is located in `~/.config/fish/functions/remove.fish`, then create `~/.config/fish/completions/remove.fish`) with the following contents:

```
complete -c remove --no-files --arguments "(<query command>)"
```

Note: If you'd like to refer to existing completions, you can see inspect the directories listed by `echo $fish_complete_path`.